# Ruby on rails binding form to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

In the section `2.2 Binding a Form to an Object` I saw that this:

```
<% form_for :article, @article, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:class => "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :size => "60x12" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

I get form like this :

```
<form action="/articles/create" method="post" class="nifty_form">
  <input id="article_title" name="article[title]" size="30" type="text" />
  <textarea id="article_body" name="article[body]" cols="60" rows="12"></textarea>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

So the controller method `create` should be executed and @action should be serialized from form to it. So do I need to declare create with some parameters like :

```
def create(action)
action.save!
end
```

Or how would I get hold of action object which I sent from form in controller method create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the form values are passed to the method as a hash. The `title` field is passed as `params[:article][:title]`, `body` as `params[:article][:body]`, etc.

So in your controller, you would need to create a new `Article` from these params. Note that you don't pass a parameter to the `create` method:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, `@article` is your object for Article model.

```
<form action="/articles/create" method="post" class="nifty_form">
```

This form's action is `"/articles/create"`, that means upon submitting the form, all the form-data will be posted to create action of articles controller. Over there, you can catch the form data through params.

So in your create action

```
def create
    # it will create an object of Article and initializes the attribute for that object
  @article = Article.new(params[:article]) # params[:article] => {:title => 'your-title-on-form', :body => 'your body entered in your form'}

  if @article.save # if your article is being created
    # your code goes here 
  else
    # you can handle the error over here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

to let create method save your object you just need to pass parameters to new object and than save it

```
def create
 Article.new(params[:article]).save
end
```

in reality method can be more difficult with redirect respond_to block and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Can do it through params.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  @article.save!  
  redirect_to :action => :index #or where ever 

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  render :action => :new
end
```